# Согласование двух определений

Tags: согласование, определения

Меня поставила в тупик фраза "федеральная сеть лабораторных отделений с собственной технологической, научной и экспертной базой".

Не понимаю, как должно быть правильно - собственной базой, собственной базами, собственными базами или с собственными базой.

Я знаю, что есть правило для определений, но не очень понимаю, применимо ли оно конкретно в этом случае. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку речь идёт о базах как о совокупностях ресурсов, необходимых для
деятельности (как, например, кормовая база, сырьевая база), а не о базах как помещениях, опорных пунктах (овощебаза, туристическая база), то следует писать: **Федеральная сеть лабораторных отделений с обственной технологической, научной и экспертной базой**.

Сравните: *научный и технический прогресс; черная и цветная металлургия; тяжелая и легкая атлетика; политическое, экономическое и культурное сотрудничество...*

Подробнее см. [соответствующий параграф в справочнике Розенталя](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091272.html#id-44%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%C2%A7194%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC).